# Document ID not set in ElasticSearch, even though it is configured inside logstash.conf

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

[Here](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/b6c3e/2) are the contents inside my `logstash.conf`.

(Apologies for not pasting the contents here directly. StackOverflow does not allow questions with an overly high code-to-text ratio.)

As a test, I ran the PowerShell command

> C:\Users\Me\Downloads\curl-7.64.1-win64-mingw\bin> .\curl.exe
>   -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:31311/twitter_new/7'

I see the following output on my Logstash terminal:

```
{
                "message" => "",
               "@version" => "1",
                   "host" => "127.0.0.1",
             "@timestamp" => 2019-04-09T11:35:22.458Z,
    "request_path_length" => 3,
                "headers" => {
              "http_host" => "127.0.0.1:31311",
         "content_length" => "0",
           "request_path" => [
            [0] "",
            [1] "twitter_new",
            [2] "7"
        ],
            "http_accept" => "*/*",
           "http_version" => "HTTP/1.1",
        "http_user_agent" => "curl/7.64.1",
         "request_method" => "PUT"
    },
               "index_id" => "twitter_new"
}
```

As you can see, `document_id` is not set to `7`, even though that is what I would expect.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I changed

```
if [request_path_length == 3] {
```

to

```
if [request_path_length] == 3 {
```

I made another `PUT` request to `/twitter_new/8`. I then made a `GET` request to retrieve all entries, and this was the entry corresponding to the latest `PUT` request I made:

```
{
    "_index": "twitter_new",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "O5AIAmoBCWsefMj-o7Fw",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "message": "",
        "document_id": "8",
        "@version": "1",
        "@timestamp": "2019-04-09T12:18:00.665Z",
        "index_id": "twitter_new",
        "request_path_length": 3,
        "headers": {
            "request_path": [
                "",
                "twitter_new",
                "8"
            ],
            "http_accept": "*/*",
            "http_version": "HTTP/1.1",
            "content_length": "0",
            "request_method": "PUT",
            "http_user_agent": "curl/7.64.1",
            "http_host": "127.0.0.1:31311"
        },
        "host": "127.0.0.1"
    }
}
```

As you can see, inside `source`, `document_id` is indeed set to `8`, but `_id` still a randomly generated string. I would expect `_id` to be `8` as well, just like how `_index` is `twitter_new`.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Can you change, `document_id => "%{[headers][request_path][2]}"` to `document_id => "%{document_id}"` and check?

Comment: Found a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your conditionals.

This is the correct way to refer to fields on a logstash pipeline:

`if [request_path_length] == 3`

You are using `if [request_path_length == 3]`, which does not work.